# Should Mac OSX have a "malloc.h" file?

Tags: c, macos, include-path

A customer's code is expecting to find an include file `malloc.h` in one of the "usual suspect" locations.  On my Mac, AFAICT, there is no `malloc.h`, at least not in any place you would expect to find it, such as `/usr/include`, `/usr/local/include`, or `/opt/local/include`.  Since the `malloc()` is usually defined in `stdlib.h`, and since the code includes stdlib.h anyway, I was able to get the code to build by just commenting out the few includes of `malloc.h`.  I am building with `gcc`.

But two questions:  Is my gcc messed up somehow?  Should that file be there?  Also, the code bombs almost immediately with a seg fault that I haven't been able to track down yet.  Could this be the consequence of using the wrong `malloc()`?

Comment: `malloc.h` does not appear to be [a standard conforming header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header) so no your installation is fine and conformant.

Comment: How could it run (and seg fault), if no malloc.h is found?  Without a needed header, it ought not build.

Comment: To use _malloc_ you have to `#include <stdlib.h>`, not _malloc.h_

Comment: A little further research shows that header to be glibc specific, and non-portable.

Comment: If you commented out the #include of malloc.h, the compiler would have assumed `malloc()` returns `int`, probably a 32-bit int.  But on a 64-bit platform, including modern Macs, pointers are 64 bits.  So if the compiler thinks `malloc` returns int, the top 32 bits of the pointer values get scraped off, and this *definitely* leads to things like "bombing immediately with a seg fault".

Comment: @Mgetz, `malloc.h` is certainly non-standard and thus non-portable, but it is not a glibc invention, nor specific to that implementation.  FreeBSD's C library has it, for example.  Glibc provides it to support non-conforming programs that depend on it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I could not find a POSIX reference for it and only found it on the GLIBC docs. Hence my statement

Comment: BSD (and System V) existed before POSIX.  Glibc has rather a lot of features aimed at supporting code written for one or the other of those using facilities that never were standardized anywhere.

Comment: I remember getting the impression that `<malloc.h>` first originated in old C compilers for MS-DOS, and that gcc and a few other Unix compilers/libraries added it just to coddle all the DOS-written code out there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `malloc.h` is deprecated and should not be used. It contains some non-standard functions too. If you want to use `malloc`, then include `stdlib.h`. Not even the C89 standard mentions `malloc.h`

If it's the cause of your problems, I don't know, but it's quite probable.

Answer (score 3):

The listing below can provide ideas on where the file *should/could* be found.  I can't explain the segfault without more details, though.  I do not see how it could be related to malloc() in any way.

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/malloc.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/malloc/malloc.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/sys/malloc.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS.sdk/usr/include/malloc/malloc.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/malloc/malloc.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS.sdk/usr/include/malloc/malloc.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/malloc.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/malloc/malloc.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/sys/malloc.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/usr/include/malloc/malloc.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator.sdk/usr/include/malloc/malloc.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/malloc/malloc.h
$
```